# java.sql.SQLException: Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring, jdbc

I am trying to run this query using java with JDBC:

```
SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE 0=0 # find all occurrences of the search string + any component of the search string
        OR job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'software', '%')
        OR job_description COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'software', '%')
        OR job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'engineer', '%')
        OR job_description COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'engineer', '%')
        AND date_posted >= now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY # ensure results are from the last month
ORDER BY
        # order first by results that begin with the search string
        job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('software engineer', '%') DESC,
        # order second by results that contain the search string
        IFNULL(NULLIF(INSTR(job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, 'software engineer'), 0), 99999) DESC,
        # order third by results that contain the first component of the search string
        IFNULL(NULLIF(INSTR(job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, 'software'), 0), 99999) DESC,
        # order forth by results that contain the second component of the search string
        IFNULL(NULLIF(INSTR(job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, 'engineer'), 0), 99999) DESC,
        # order alphabetically
        job_title,
        IFNULL(NULLIF(INSTR(job_description COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, 'software engineer'), 0), 99999);
```

When I run this query in the MySQL terminal it runs fine. However, when I run it through JDBC, where `searchTokens = ['software', 'engineer']`

```
var searchTokens = searchValue.split(" ");

String query = "SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE 0=0 \n";

for (String token : searchTokens) {
    query += String.format("    OR job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%%', '%s', '%%')\n", token);
    query += String.format("    OR job_description COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%%', '%s', '%%')\n", token);
}

query += "    AND date_posted >= now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY\n ORDER BY\n";
query += String.format("    job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%s', '%%') DESC,\n", searchValue);
query +=
    String.format("    IFNULL(NULLIF(INSTR(job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, '%s'), 0), 99999),\n", searchValue);

for (String token : searchTokens) {
    query +=
        String.format("    IFNULL(NULLIF(INSTR(job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, '%s'), 0), 99999),\n", token);
}

query += String.format("    job_title,\n" +
        "    IFNULL(NULLIF(INSTR(job_description COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, '%s'), 0), 99999);", searchValue);

List<Map<String, Object>> result = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query);
```

I get this error:

```
nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [SELECT * FROM jobs WHERE 0=0 
    OR job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'software', '%')
    OR job_description COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'software', '%')
    OR job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'engineer', '%')
    OR job_description COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'engineer', '%')
    AND date_posted >= now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
 ORDER BY
    job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('software engineer', '%') DESC,
    IFNULL(NULLIF(INSTR(job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, 'software engineer'), 0), 99999),
    IFNULL(NULLIF(INSTR(job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, 'software'), 0), 99999),
    IFNULL(NULLIF(INSTR(job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, 'engineer'), 0), 99999),
    job_title,
    IFNULL(NULLIF(INSTR(job_description COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, 'software engineer'), 0), 99999);]; SQL state [HY001]; error code [1038]; Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Out of sort memory, consider increasing server sort buffer size
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1200) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar:8.0.17]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1QueryStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:439) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:376) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:452) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:462) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.queryForList(JdbcTemplate.java:490) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.jobtech.controller.JobroleSearchController.submit(JobroleSearchController.java:49) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:105) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:878) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:792) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:652) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1589) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.37.jar:9.0.37]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830) ~[na:na]
```

I have tried setting sort_buffer_size to 256K, and this error is still persisting. However, I have read that it is bad to set the sort buffer size too large. What is causing my error in this SQL statement when it runs perfectly fine in the MySQL terminal?

Comment: *FYI:* Operator precedence means that `WHERE a OR b OR c AND d` means `WHERE a OR b OR (c AND d)`, and since first expression is `0=0`, your query is running as-if there was **no WHERE clause** at all, i.e. it is processing the ***entire table***. No wonder the sort buffer runs full.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably fix the out-of-memory problem by fixing the `where` clause.  The filtering on date only applies to the last condition, because the parentheses are wrong.

So:

```
WHERE (job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'software', '%') OR
       job_description COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'software', '%') OR
       job_title COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'engineer', '%') OR
       ob_description COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE CONCAT('%', 'engineer', '%')
      ) AND
      date_posted >= now() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Note:  For performance you might want to consider a full-text index on this table.  Also, using `collate` in the query suggests a data modeling problem.  If you want a case-insensitive search . . . well that is the normal default in MySQL anyway.

Comment: How would I increase the performance in this scenario using full-text?

Comment: @JimmyNesbitt . . . Using a full text index -- with the right collation -- should improve performance.  You can read about them in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the internal buffer of the database is to small for the query.

You can increase the buffer in the following config file `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
sort_buffer_size to 512K
```

Comment: But if so, why does this query run fine straight through mysql?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the 0=0. Sry! This means that the clause is always true as the others have already written. I would say that a direct SQL query uses the sort buffer more efficient than the Java statement, which causes the error only under Java.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the internal buffer of the database is too small for the query.

Run the below query in MySQL command to increase the memory

```
SET GLOBAL sort_buffer_size = 512000000; // It'll reset after server restart
```

To set permanent, edit the below file and add:

```
sudo nano /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

sort_buffer_size = 512000000;

sudo service mysql restart
```

Note that 1073741824 is equal to bytes and will result in 1 GB memory allocation.

Also, there is a possibility that something else causing the issue, you can check CPU, memory and slow query logs

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS
```

You can then analyse the output base on current buffer pool size.

```
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
BUFFER POOL AND MEMORY
----------------------
Total large memory allocated 412090368
Dictionary memory allocated 380237
Buffer pool size   24576
Free buffers       23618
Database pages     954
Old database pages 372
Modified db pages  0
Pending reads      0
```

For more details, refer to MySQL docs: [MySQL Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-optimization.html)